# Add range key to DynamoDB table without destroying the table

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, terraform

I have a table with only hash key, I want to add new range key and GSI using terraform without impacting the data in the table or destroying it.

**I know it have the prevent_destroy = true.
what I want to update the table without remove or destroy the old data.**

old one:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "table" {
  name         = "table_example"
  hash_key     = "hash"

  attribute {
    name = "hash"
    type = "S"
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }

}
```

after update:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "table" {
  name         = "table_example"
  hash_key     = "hash"
  range_key    = "range"

  attribute {
    name = "hash"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "range"
    type = "S"
  }

  global_secondary_index {
    name            = "gsi-example"
    hash_key        = "range"
    projection_type = "ALL"
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }

}
```

Comment: You can't update a DynamoDB table in place (via Terraform or any other way) to add a new range key unfortunately. You should be able to omit the `range_key` here and instead use the GSI as a secondary index mapping to that `range` attribute but if you want to modify the DynamoDB table to require the `range` attribute as a range key as well then you will need to create a new table alongside it and then manually import the data from your old table.

Comment: Was really helpful to know I'd have to back up my table before adding the `index`. I'm pretty new to terraform, and this got me wondering, does using terraform, wipe out any other manually added settings? (I had originally added the `index` manually to aws and had it disappeared). When I say 'any other manually added settings', I'm thinking more about things like the custom domain and certificates I added (manually) to api gateway (which I will now need to figure out how to add in code). I guess terraforming is usually a bit like a `put` instead of a `patch` operation in databases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **can't do this**. Any changes to [KeySchema](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-keyschema) **require replacement**.

You have to backup your data, create new table when you updated, and re-upload it. Alternatively, create a GSI with your sort key. This way you can keep your primary table as is, and operate on GSI when needed to use sort key as well.